# Dart - Map with List as a value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this:

```
  List<ForumCategories>? forumCategories;
  var mainCats = List<ForumCategories>.empty(growable: true);
  var subCats = <int, List<ForumCategories>>{};
```

Than this is what I do in order to populate it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < forumCategories!.length; i++) {
  if (forumCategories![i].main == 0) {
    subCats[forumCategories![i].slave]?.add(forumCategories![i]);
  }
}
```

And than when I do:

```
var size = subCats.length;
print("SUBCATS: $size");
```

Output is always: `SUBCATS: 0`

This does not populate the map. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 1):

because you're trying to add an item to a null List, see here:

```
if (forumCategories![i].main == 0) {
subCats[forumCategories![i].slave]?.add(forumCategories![i]);
}
```

`subCats[forumCategories![i].slave]` does not exist yet in your map, it's like you saying:

```
null.add(forumCategories![i]);
```

nothing will happen.
you need to initialize it by an empty `List` if it's `null` like this:

```
if (forumCategories![i].main == 0) {

(subCats[forumCategories![i].slave] ?? []).add(forumCategories![i]) // this will assign an empty list only the first time when it's null, then it adds elements to it.
 }
```

now before adding elements to that list it will find the empty list to add.

Comment: Could be combined to `(subCats[forumCategories![i].slave] ?? []).add(forumCategories![i])`, which would avoid repeated lookups, repeated null assertions, and which would eliminate a null assertion.

Comment: yes you have a point on this